# Why does the cost in my implementation of a deep neural network increase after a few iterations?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am a beginner in machine learning and neural networks. Recently, after watching Andrew Ng's lectures on deep learning, I tried to implement a binary classifier using deep neural networks on my own.
However, the cost of the function is expected to decrease after each iteration.
In my program, it decreases slightly in the beginning, but rapidly increases later. I tried to make changes in learning rate and number of iterations, but to no avail. I am very confused.
Here is my code

**1. Neural network classifier class**

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, X, Y, dimensions, alpha=1.2, iter=3000):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.dimensions = dimensions    # Including input layer and output layer. Let example be dimensions=4
        self.alpha = alpha  # Learning rate
        self.iter = iter    # Number of iterations
        self.length = len(self.dimensions)-1
        self.params = {}    # To store parameters W and b for each layer
        self.cache = {}     # To store cache Z and A for each layer
        self.grads = {}     # To store dA, dZ, dW, db
        self.cost = 1       # Initial value does not matter

    def initialize(self):
        np.random.seed(3)
        # If dimensions is 4, then layer 0 and 3 are input and output layers
        # So we only need to initialize w1, w2 and w3
        # There is no need of w0 for input layer
        for l in range(1, len(self.dimensions)):
            self.params['W'+str(l)] = np.random.randn(self.dimensions[l], self.dimensions[l-1])*0.01
            self.params['b'+str(l)] = np.zeros((self.dimensions[l], 1))

    def forward_propagation(self):
        self.cache['A0'] = self.X
        # For last layer, ie, the output layer 3, we need to activate using sigmoid
        # For layer 1 and 2, we need to use relu
        for l in range(1, len(self.dimensions)-1):
            self.cache['Z'+str(l)] = np.dot(self.params['W'+str(l)], self.cache['A'+str(l-1)]) + self.params['b'+str(l)]
            self.cache['A'+str(l)] = relu(self.cache['Z'+str(l)])
        l = len(self.dimensions)-1
        self.cache['Z'+str(l)] = np.dot(self.params['W'+str(l)], self.cache['A'+str(l-1)]) + self.params['b'+str(l)]
        self.cache['A'+str(l)] = sigmoid(self.cache['Z'+str(l)])

    def compute_cost(self):
        m = self.Y.shape[1]
        A = self.cache['A'+str(len(self.dimensions)-1)]
        self.cost = -1/m*np.sum(np.multiply(self.Y, np.log(A)) + np.multiply(1-self.Y, np.log(1-A)))
        self.cost = np.squeeze(self.cost)

    def backward_propagation(self):
        A = self.cache['A' + str(len(self.dimensions) - 1)]
        m = self.X.shape[1]
        self.grads['dA'+str(len(self.dimensions)-1)] = -(np.divide(self.Y, A) - np.divide(1-self.Y, 1-A))
        # Sigmoid derivative for final layer
        l = len(self.dimensions)-1
        self.grads['dZ' + str(l)] = self.grads['dA' + str(l)] * sigmoid_prime(self.cache['Z' + str(l)])
        self.grads['dW' + str(l)] = 1 / m * np.dot(self.grads['dZ' + str(l)], self.cache['A' + str(l - 1)].T)
        self.grads['db' + str(l)] = 1 / m * np.sum(self.grads['dZ' + str(l)], axis=1, keepdims=True)
        self.grads['dA' + str(l - 1)] = np.dot(self.params['W' + str(l)].T, self.grads['dZ' + str(l)])
        # Relu derivative for previous layers
        for l in range(len(self.dimensions)-2, 0, -1):
            self.grads['dZ'+str(l)] = self.grads['dA'+str(l)] * relu_prime(self.cache['Z'+str(l)])
            self.grads['dW'+str(l)] = 1/m*np.dot(self.grads['dZ'+str(l)], self.cache['A'+str(l-1)].T)
            self.grads['db'+str(l)] = 1/m*np.sum(self.grads['dZ'+str(l)], axis=1, keepdims=True)
            self.grads['dA'+str(l-1)] = np.dot(self.params['W'+str(l)].T, self.grads['dZ'+str(l)])

    def update_parameters(self):
        for l in range(1, len(self.dimensions)):
            self.params['W'+str(l)] = self.params['W'+str(l)] - self.alpha*self.grads['dW'+str(l)]
            self.params['b'+str(l)] = self.params['b'+str(l)] - self.alpha*self.grads['db'+str(l)]

    def train(self):
        np.random.seed(1)
        self.initialize()
        for i in range(self.iter):
            #print(self.params)
            self.forward_propagation()
            self.compute_cost()
            self.backward_propagation()
            self.update_parameters()
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print('Cost after {} iterations is {}'.format(i, self.cost))
```

**2. Testing code for odd or even number classifier**

```
import numpy as np
from main import NeuralNetwork
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
Y = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
clf = NeuralNetwork(X, Y, [1, 1, 1], alpha=0.003, iter=7000)
clf.train()
```

**3. Helper Code**

```
import math
import numpy as np

def sigmoid_scalar(x):
    return 1/(1+math.exp(-x))
def sigmoid_prime_scalar(x):
    return sigmoid_scalar(x)*(1-sigmoid_scalar(x))
def relu_scalar(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x
    else:
        return 0
def relu_prime_scalar(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
sigmoid = np.vectorize(sigmoid_scalar)
sigmoid_prime = np.vectorize(sigmoid_prime_scalar)
relu = np.vectorize(relu_scalar)
relu_prime = np.vectorize(relu_prime_scalar)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1. Have you tried a lower learning rate (`1E-5`) 2. Have you tried scaling your input? Maybe something as simple as `X = X / 10` might be enough for your use case.

Comment: I tried lowering the learning rate

Comment: Cost decrease to a point and becomes constant

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira please read my comment

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I also scaled the input and tried again, it initially decreases from 0.69 to 0.58 and then becomes constant

Answer (score 1):

I believe your cross-entropy derivative is wrong. Instead of this:

```
# WRONG!
self.grads['dA'+str(len(self.dimensions)-1)] = -(np.divide(self.Y, A) - np.divide(1-self.Y, A))
```

... do this:

```
# CORRECT
self.grads['dA'+str(len(self.dimensions)-1)] = np.divide(A - self.Y, (1 - A) *  A)
```

See [these lecture notes](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pjsadows/notes.pdf) for the details. I think you meant the formula (5), but forgot `1-A`. Anyway, use formula (6).

Comment: I did correct it. Still ain't working. I mean the gradient descent is working but the results aren't satisfactory. The error decreases initially but very slowly and then becomes constant at a significantly high value. I tried different combinations of learning rate and number of iterations, but to no avail

Comment: Mod 2 isn't easy for NN to learn, especially with 1 neuron in each layer. Your next step is to make it "wide", not only "deep".

Comment: Yes. Then I trained it with another examples which was a data set in andrew ng's course's week 2 assignment. In the assignment, it begun with a cost of 0.69 and reached very near to 0. But with the same example, I'm getting maximum upto 0.23. I used 1 hidden layer with 4 neurons.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for hours solving the same problem with the cost function in the IRIS dataset classification. For me the problem was the regularization parameter that was way too high. After setting it to 0 and tuning a bit here and there I got the 100% accuracy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).